# Why does this `display-buffer-alist` rule not do what I expect?

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist, display-buffer

I have the following in the `display-buffer-alist` list:

```lisp
    (("*"
      (display-buffer-in-side-window
       ((side . left)
        (window-width . 110)))))
```

While `display-buffer-overriding-action` is `(nil)`.

If I understand correctly, this means that `(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "New buffer"))` should be equivalent to `(display-buffer-in-side-window (get-buffer-create "New buffer") '((side . left) (window-width . 110))`.

But it is not: the first command opens the buffer `New buffer` at the bottom, but the second one opens it at the left.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the correct code is

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         '(".*" display-buffer-in-side-window
          (side . left) (window-width . 110)))
```

The differences are:

- As Toby Speight said, `".*"` should be used in place of `"*"`.
- The function `display-buffer-in-side-window` and its arguments should be on the same level as the regex, i.e. not `(regex (fun args))` but `(regex fun args)`.

Answer (score 1):

The condition needs to be a regular expression, but `"*"` is not a valid regular expression.  If you want to match all buffers, you need `".*"` (or perhaps an empty string).